# implement the inode table to include a single indirect block and set block size in fusepy

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system, fuse

I am trying to implement a inode table to include a single indirect block only that means no double or triple indirect blocks...Next i want to set the size of each data block to 8 kb.

I am using Fusepy library to implement a fuse file system . I want to do all the above task in fuse file system in python.How do i go about doing that. 
Also i have to limit the size of whole file system to 1 mb..

Any ideas how to implement this in python using fuse file system.

the following is the sample code of how to implement fuse file system in python which i am using..

https://www.stavros.io/posts/python-fuse-filesystem/